# How to place single comma after two equations so it's placed between two strings

Tags: formatting, align, punctuation

I'm sorry for my English, please let me know how I should have formulated my question properly.
So I have the code

```
    \begin{align*}
    f(x) &= \sin(x) & x \in[0, 1] \\
    g(x) &= \cos(x)
    \end{align*}
```

and it gives the following result

[image]

I want this "x \in [0, 1]" part to be placed between these two strings with comma preceding it, something like this 
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `aligned` to generate an `align`-like block, and then place the conditions after it. I don't particularly like the placement of `,`, so suggest that you remove it since it makes sense without it. Alternatively one can use an `rcases` environment (from [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)), perhaps.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{aligned}
    f(x) &= \sin(x) \\
    g(x) &= \cos(x)
  \end{aligned}, \qquad x \in [0, 1]
\]

\[
  \begin{rcases}
    f(x) = \sin(x) \\
    g(x) = \cos(x)
  \end{rcases} \quad x \in [0, 1]
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility using the `empheq` package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}


\begin{empheq}[right={\empheqrbrace, \qquad x \in [0, 1]}]{align*}
    f(x) &= \sin(x) \\
    g(x) &= \cos(x)
\end{empheq}


\begin{empheq}[right={, \qquad x \in [0, 1]}]{align*}
    f(x) &= \sin(x) \\
    g(x) &= \cos(x)
\end{empheq}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: +1 for mentioning `empheq` but I would not put a comma there. It looks very lonely and unhappy, and can be mistaken for a prime.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, I wouldn't too, I actually started my answer based on Werner's ^^

Answer (score 3):

A last solution with the `\ArrowBetweenLines` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

 \begin{alignat*}{2}
    f(x) &= \sin(x) & & \\
\ArrowBetweenLines*[,\enspace \forall x\in {[0,1]}]
    g(x) &= \cos(x) & &
    \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]